# Data not added accurately through stored procedure (Oracle 11g R2)

Tags: stored-procedures, oracle11g

I have a temp table, data in which is loaded through sqlldr. The data in the temp table is added as follows:

```
PHONE       ADDRESS     ORDER_ID
9971410000  D-166 GF    1
9910020000  H-12D       2
9873120000  K-19C       3
9811120000  J-200       4
9873120000  K-19C       5
9810320000  N-29B       6
9810390000  J-235 GF    7
9873500000  M-39        8
8447910000  J-62 GF     9
9873120000  K-19C       10
```

After the data is inserted into the 'temp' table, a trigger calls a procedure to insert into other tables:

```
 create or replace TRIGGER insert_customer
 AFTER INSERT ON temp
 FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
   insert_address(:new.phno, :new.addr, :new.ord_id);
 END;
```

The procedure is as follows:

```
   create or replace procedure INSERT_ADDRESS(
   p_cust_phone customer.cust_phone%type, 
   p_address address.address%type, 
   p_ord_id customer_order.order_id%type
   )
   is
   l_cust_id customer.cust_id%type;
   l_address_id address.address_id%type;
   begin
     begin
      select cust_id 
      into l_cust_id 
      from customer c
      where c.cust_phone=p_cust_phone;
    exception
      when no_data_found then
      insert into customer 
      values (cust_id_seq.nextval, 'No Name', p_cust_phone)
      returning cust_id into l_cust_id;
    end;

      select address_id
      into l_address_id
      from address a
      where a.address=p_address;
  exception
      when no_data_found then
      insert into address
      values (address_id_seq.nextval, UPPER(p_address), UPPER(p_area))
      returning address_id into l_address_id;

  insert into customer_address
  values (l_cust_id, l_address_id);

  insert into customer_order (order_id, cust_id)
  values (p_ord_id,l_cust_id);

  end;
```

The data inserted in the CUSTOMER_ORDER table is not correct. The result I get on the following query is listed below:

```
select * from customer_order;

ord_id   cust_id
1         1
2         2
3         3
4         4
6         5
7         6
8         7
9         8
```

The order_id (5,10) are lost since they come from the same customer as ord_id=3. Multiple orders by the same customer are not added in the customer_order table. I am not able to understand where did I make a mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your insert into customer_order only takes place if the address being passed in doesn't exist in the address table already - you've got it in the exception clause of the insert_address procedure.

What I would do instead is to create a package, and then have the steps to get/store the customer and address details as separate functions. That way, you get easier to understand code, which makes it easier to maintain, debug etc.

Something like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY customer_pkg
AS
  FUNCTION get_customer_id (p_cust_phone customer.cust_phone%TYPE)
  RETURN customer.cust_id%TYPE
  IS
    l_cust_id customer.cust_id%TYPE;
  BEGIN
    SELECT cust_id
    INTO   l_cust_id
    FROM   customer
    WHERE  cust_phone = p_cust_phone;

  EXCEPTION
    WHEN no_data_found THEN
      INSERT INTO customer (cust_id, cust_name, cust_phone)
      VALUES (cust_id_seq.nextval, 'No Name', p_cust_phone)
      RETURNING cust_id INTO l_cust_id;
  END get_customer_id;

  FUNCTION get_address_id (p_address address.address%TYPE)
  RETURN address.address_id%TYPE
  IS
    l_address_id address.address_id%TYPE;
  BEGIN
    SELECT address_id
    INTO   l_address_id
    FROM   address
    WHERE  address = p_address;

  EXCEPTION
    WHEN no_data_found THEN
      INSERT INTO address (address_id, address)
      VALUES (address_id_seq.nextval, p_address)
      RETURNING address_id INTO l_address_id;
  END get_address_id;

  PROCEDURE insert_order(p_cust_phone customer.cust_phone%TYPE,
                         p_address    address.address_i%TYPE,
                         p_ord_id     customer_order.order_id%TYPE)
  IS
    l_cust_id customer.cust_id%TYPE;
    l_address_id address.address_id%TYPE;
  BEGIN
    l_cust_id := get_customer_id (p_cust_phone => p_cust_phone);
    l_address_id := get_address_id (p_address => p_address);

    INSERT INTO customer_order (order_id, cust_id)
    VALUES (p_ord_id, l_cust_id);
  END insert_order;

END customer_pkg;
/
```

Then your trigger would look like:

```
create or replace TRIGGER insert_customer
 AFTER INSERT ON temp
 FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
   customer_pkg.insert_order(p_cust_phone => :new.phno,
                             p_address => :new.addr,
                             p_ord_id => :new.ord_id);
 END insert_customer;
```

Comment: Your procedure is correct but it misses one thing. Where do you add rows into 'CUSTOMER_ADDRESS" table which is the junction table between 'CUSTOMER' and 'ADDRESS'. The cust_id and the address_id are to be inserted in the CUSTOMER_ADDRESS table too so as to link them.

Comment: I'm sure you can look at my procedure and work out where you need to add the additional insert.

Comment: The values of 'l_cust_id' and 'l_address_id' are needed together to perform the insert on the CUSTOMER_ADDRESS. Since both are in different functions, how do I use them? That was the problem because of which I used the same procedure to insert into all tables. I am relatively new to pl/sql.

Comment: So, I'm guessing the insert into customer_address needs to take place in the get_address_id function. Hint: it's easy to add another parameter to a function or procedure...

Comment: ohh ok, got it. Thanks :D